# Revisit "example of an unstable fixed point for which the linearized dynamics are stable"

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I am reading the following discussion:

[example of an unstable fixed point for which the linearized dynamics are stable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403662/example-of-an-unstable-fixed-point-for-which-the-linearized-dynamics-are-stable)

The above discussion is for the vector field (continuous time).

Is there an example for the discrete time (map)?

$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$$

I know that for the linearization case $$x_{n+1} = Ax_n,$$ if $|\lambda(A)| <1$, it is stable; $|\lambda(A)| >1$, unstable.

Is there an example of a map which has a fixed point stable in the linearization approximation but unstable in the original nonlinear system?

Comment: $f(x) = x + x^3$.

Comment: @user539887 the linear approximation at $x=0$ is $x_{n+1} = 1$, which could be inconclusive?  exactly on the unit circle. How about $f(x) = 0.1x+x^3$?

Comment: The linear approximation at $x=0$ is the identity map.